# vue3 project package to android apk can't open pdf file with pdfjs

Tags: android, vuejs3, apk, pdf.js

my vue3 project use pdfjs can realize pdf file Online preview, but when i package this vue project to apk, it can't work well on android system, pdf file Always loading ,can't display, that's why.

this is my code for pdf file online preview.

```
import VuePdfEmbed from "vue-pdf-embed"
import {createLoadingTask} from "vue3-pdfjs";

const loadingTask = createLoadingTask({url:state.source});
loadingTask.promise.then((pdf:{numPages:number}) => {
  state.numPages = pdf.numPages
});
```

expect vue3 project package to android apk also can realize pdf file Online preview.thank you !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.